# Why is apache2 still listed in service --status-all after being removed?

Tags: service

Ubuntu 18.04 (but I assume the same would happen on most/all Debian based systems)

I've removed apache2 and postfix completely using `apt remove apache2 postfix`

Yet they're still listed (along with `apache-htcacheclean`) in the services.

I've tried stopping, disabling, unmasking them - but it still shows in the list of services. How come, and can they be removed?

```
root@hosting:/home/username# service --status-all
 ...
 [ + ]  apache-htcacheclean
 [ - ]  apache2
 ...
 [ - ]  postfix
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

First enter the following command:

`systemctl daemon-reload`

Then check the services again with `service --status-all`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just deleting them from the /etc/init.d/ directory.